# Neo4j streams.publish procedure not found error

Tags: neo4j

**CALL streams.publish('topic', 'hello_message')**

Results into following error:

Their is no procedure with the name streams.publish registered for this database instance. Please ensure you have spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Neo4j version: 3.5.14

Neo4j.conf includes:

**dbms.security.procedures.whitelist**=streams.*, Apoc.coll.*

Also, Installed plugin neo4j.streams-3.5.5

Answer (score 0):

The white listing [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/securing-extensions/#white-listing) states:

> The list may contain both fully-qualified procedure names, and partial
>   names with the wildcard `*`.

Try using the wildcard character "*" in the list:

```
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=streams.*,apoc.coll.*
```

Comment: Already added... But no improvement. Still facing the same error.